# mapply on pairs of elements in a lists in R

Tags: r, mapply

If I have a symmetric binary operator that I want to apply over the pairs of elements from a list, is there an easy way I can do this in R? I tried:

```
A <- list(1,2,3)
mapply(function(x,y) x+y, A,A)
```

but this only gives `x[n]+y[n]` for all `n=1..N` but I want `x[n]+y[m]` for all `m=1..n, n=1..N` returned as a list. `outer(..)` does that for `m=1..N, n=1..N` which involves redundant computation so I want to discount that.

Notice I don't want solution to this simple example. I need a general solution that works for non-numeric input as well. The thing I'm trying to do is like:

```
mapply(function(set_1, set_2) setequal(intersect(set_1, set_2),  set_3), list_of_sets, list_of_sets)
```

In both cases addition and intersection are symmetric. In the first example, I expect `list(3,4,5)` from `list(1+2,1+3,2+3)`. For the second case me input `list_of_sets` is:

```
> list_of_sets
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]]
[1] 3

[[6]]
[1] 1 3

[[7]]
[1] 2 3

[[8]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

and `set_3` being `c(1,2)` as a simple example.

Comment: Something like `mapply(\`+\`, list(1,2,3), list(c(1,2,3)) )`  maybe?

Comment: Ok just voted for reopening this question

Comment: @monotonic I showed an option with `combn`  Does it work for you?

Comment: what do you expect as output for `list_of_sets`?

Answer (score 5):

You may use `outer` -

```
values <- c(1, 2, 3)
outer(values, values, `+`)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3    4
#[2,]    3    4    5
#[3,]    4    5    6
```

---

`outer` also works for non-numeric input. If the function that you want to apply is not vectorised you can use `Vectorize`. Since OP did not provide an example I have created one of my own.

```
list_of_sets_1 <- list(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c('a'))
list_of_sets_2 <- list(c('a', 'c'), c('a', 'b'))

fun <- function(x, y) intersect(x, y)
result <- outer(list_of_sets_1, list_of_sets_2, Vectorize(fun))
result
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't apply to more complicated input though. I'm just using that case as an example.

Comment: I've edited to include an example.

Comment: I edited the question a bit more to make it more specific for symmetric binary operators.

Answer (score 1):

We need `combn` to do pairwise computation without redundancy

```
combn(A, 2, FUN = function(x) x[[1]] + x[[2]], simplify = FALSE)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

---

This will also work with non-numeric elements

```
list_of_sets <- list(c('a', 'b', 'c'), "a", c("a", "c"))
combn(list_of_sets, 2, FUN = function(x) Reduce(intersect, x), simplify = FALSE)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "c"

[[3]]
[1] "a"
```

We may also do

```
combn(list_of_sets, 2, FUN = function(x) 
   setequal(intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), set_3), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the question a little bit. Is it possible to do this without 'Reduce'?

Comment: @monotonic did you meant `combn(list_of_sets, 2, FUN = function(x) intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: @monotonic is it possible for you to show the expected output for the `list_of_sets` along with the input data so that it is easier to test

Comment: Sure. An example: `> set_1
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]]
[1] 3

[[6]]
[1] 1 3

[[7]]
[1] 2 3

[[8]]
[1] 1 2 3`

Comment: @monotonic please update your post with a small reprodcuible example and expected output.  From the comments, it is difficult to read

Comment: @montonic do you want `combn(list_of_sets, 2, FUN = function(x) 
   setequal(intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), set_3), simplify = FALSE)`